# VLC media player stable PPA for 10.10?

Tags: 10.10, ppa, vlc

After using both Ubuntu 11.04 (for Unity) and Fedora 15 (for GNOME 3), I've reverted back to Ubuntu 10.10 for its better classic gnome experience, and have no plans to upgrade until Oneiric releases (for its Unity and GNOME 3 compatibility altogether), and since 10.10 is older now, the VLC media player in its official repository is way to old, and I'm looking for PPA that provides latest stable VLC in Maverick.

So far, I've tried `ppa:ferramroberto/vlc` and `ppa:n-muench/vlc` PPAs, and both say that they have VLC 1.1.10 in the repositories, but after adding the PPA and updating the package information, I do not see updated version of VLC in synaptic, also, running `sudo apt-get install vlc mozilla-plugin-vlc` shows dependency issues and prevents installing anything. So, what's going wrong? other working PPA suggestions are welcome. Compiling the latest version of VLC manually, or using Lucid-Bleed PPA (which is available for 10.04 only but is known to work in 10.10 as well) would be my last option.

Thanks.

Comment: What's problematic about 11.04's classic gnome? I'm using it on several computers and did not notice problems yet.

Comment: 11.04 has classic Gnome but it is not same as what 10.10 had, I faced several issues and bugs in there, see my [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/42768/drop-shadow-and-other-ui-issues-with-classic-interface) regarding that.

Comment: Did you happen to edit your 

    /etc/apt/sources.list file
For a universe mirror? And of course adding in

    % sudo apt-get update
    % sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-plugin-pulse mozilla-plugin-vlc

Comment: @zkriesse: Yes, Universe repositories are enabled and package information is up-to-date. But current repository version of VLC, i.e. 1.1.4 is very out-dated so I don't want to install that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extensive PPA [here](https://launchpad.net/~maverick-bleed/+archive/ppa) - which is very similar to the [lucid bleeding edge ppa](https://launchpad.net/~lucid-bleed/+archive/ppa) (and with the same author) - will uplift maverick to the latest versions of various applications including v1.1.10 of VLC.

However, I would use this PPA with care since it will uplift approx. 69 packages.

I would add the PPA, followed by

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install vlc
```

This should upgrade vlc to the latest version.

Then I would untick the PPA from software sources and re-run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This will stop any further packages from the PPA being installed.

Note - I cannot vouch for the stability/safety or otherwise of any packages from this PPA.  As for the majority of PPA's - use at your own risk.

Comment: does this PPA upgrades any other packages expect for VLC, if I install it??

Comment: have a look at the package details of vlc - they look like the same packages as in the standard repository.  Therefore - in theory, these vlc packages should be upgraded if you have them installed.

Comment: Thanks, a brief look at PPA description and listed packages convinces me to use it.