# can't get updatemanger to update vlc

Tags: 10.10, update-manager, updates, vlc

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick and trying to update vlc from the new PPA ppa:ferramroberto/vlc . Update Manger just says Other updates `(LP-PPA-ferrnroberto-vlc)`  then shows  `libirary for encoding/decoding of Dirac video streams  libschroedinger-1.0-0(size: 254KB)`  . But doesn't let me check mark it to update it. I have the following settings checked marked  `Important Security upadtes , Reconmended updates , Check for updates Daily , Only notify about avalible updats ,
and Release upgrades set to Normal.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you examine the [package details](https://launchpad.net/~ferramroberto/+archive/vlc/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=maverick) for that PPA you'll notice that both the i386 & amd64 builds of the vlc package failed.

It does not look like the author of the PPA has pushed for the new version of vlc to be rebuilt.

My suggestion is to follow my [answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52917/vlc-media-player-stable-ppa-for-10-10/53000#53000) to upgrade your version of VLC to 1.1.10.

Note, first untick the `ferrnroberto ppa` from Software Sources and do a Reload before adding the new PPA.

Comment: Thanks that seems to have worked. I'm cool with it updating apps i don't use often .